# What is the logic behind while(sline >> n >> c && c== ',')?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, while-loop

```
vector<int> ParseLine (string line){
  istringstream sline(line);

  char c;
  int n;
  vector<int> row;
  while(sline >> n >> c && c == ",")
        row.push_back(n);

  return row;
}
```

This is one of the functions to read 2d vector from the file. I was wondering the logic behind the while loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does several things in series, in order, this code:

1. `sline >> n` Reads an integer from `sline` into variable `n`. Importantly, this also *returns* `sline`.
2. We now effectively have `sline >> c` which reads a character from `sline` into variable `c`.
3. The `&&` operator returns true only when both sides are true. `sline >> c` will once again return `sline` which will evaluate to true as long as there are characters left to read.
4. `c == ","` Checks that `c` is a comma. This should probably be changed to `c == ','` so that its a character == character comparison instead of a comparison between a character and a string.
5. Then in the loop body the integer `n` is appended to the vector `row`. This saves the integer so that when we return `row` at the end this integer will be an element.

The overall effect is that a string of comma separated integers is interpreted as a vector of integers. Note that this code should work for vectors with any number of elements, but only if there is a comma after every number. (E.G. `"45, 52, 4,"` but not `"45, 52, 4"`)

Comment: Also, I just want to point out that if you are new to programming, please do not adopt this sort of coding style. It does not make your code run any faster to do this, and makes it much more difficult for others to understand (As demonstrated by you asking this question). The clearer you make your intent, the better.

Comment: `which will evaluate to true as long as there are characters left to read.`, no it will return true as long as the steam is in the `good` state, it can return true when there are no characters left and it can also return false when there are characters left but a previous operation failed

Comment: Re: "please do not adopt this sort of coding style" -- what do you recommend instead? Yes, beginners find this sort of code hard to read, but I don't write code for beginners. For an experienced programmer the intent is clear, and pretty much anything else just becomes noisy. Don't (get me started (on (redundant parentheses))). <g>

Comment: @Pete Becker Redundant parentheses are great. Only time I don't use extra parentheses is when the order of operations is already common knowledge (like multiplication before addition). Why are you optimizing for compactness of the source file? Surely if it saves even a small amount of debugging time, the tiny amount of "noise" added is worth it.

Comment: Okay, I asked you not to get me started on redundant parentheses, but if you insist <g>: parentheses around a subexpression are for grouping; when parentheses are used even though the grouping is correct without them, I'd rather not spend time having to figure out that they're meaningless. `if ((x != 3) && (x != 4))` is so common in beginners' code here; it needs to be pointed out. Redundant parentheses often mean "I don't know how this works". I'm especially annoyed by compilers that warn about `a && b || c && d`.

Comment: @Pete Becker a && b || c && d absolutely should incur a compiler warning, since your intention is unclear. There is more to writing good code than speed and syntactic correctness. I also do not understand why ((x != 3) && (x != 4)) is any harder for you to understand. Sure, maybe most people could understand the code without that, but this only makes the order of operations explicit.

Comment: `a && b || c && d` is **exactly like** `a * b + c * d`, which you said earlier doesn't need parentheses. Boolean algebra! And note that it's **not** "order of operations", which is a runtime thing, but grouping and precedence, which determines the **meaning** of an expression.

Comment: @Pete Becker it is not "exactly like" because the latter (a * b + C * d) is something people are taught in grade school, and is therefore common knowledge. And if somebody included brackets in the (a * b + c * d), I don't think that would be a bad thing, just unnecessary. And I used the term order of operations in the sense you learn it in grade school mathematics, not the order in which the expressions are actually evaluated. Note: I also believe that code that relies on side effects of one part of the expression happening before later parts of the expression is also bad practice.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me for expecting programmers to have more than an elementary school education. Your experience must be different from mine.